# SuiteCRM is not installed

Tags: installation, suitecrm

I am unable to install the SuiteCRM on my laptop.

> Fatal error: $GLOBALS can only be modified using the $GLOBALS[$name] =
> $value syntax in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Suite\SuiteCRM-7.12.8\install\performSetup.php on line
> 715

I expected I will download the SuiteCRM very easily but it not happened

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: which version of PHP, Apache, and MySQL do you have? Also which version of SuiteCRM you are trying to install? posting complete details will enable others to answer your question quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

1. Go to C:\xampp\htdocs\Suite\SuiteCRM-7.12.8\install\performSetup.php
2. Go to line 715
3. Change it to $GLOBALS['GLOBALS'] = $varStack;
4. Save

I was losing my mind trying to solve this problem